# flutter - viewing .pub-cache files gives Request textDocument/documentSymbol failed

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I get these error messages every time I view the code of third party flutter packages (in .pub-cache folder):

```
[Error - 7:19:24 PM] Request textDocument/documentSymbol failed.
  Message: Invalid file path
  Code: -32003 
/Users/benjaminfarquhar/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/hive-1.4.4+1/lib/src/hive_impl.dart
[Error - 7:19:24 PM] Request textDocument/codeAction failed.
  Message: Invalid file path
  Code: -32003 
/Users/benjaminfarquhar/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/hive-1.4.4+1/lib/src/hive_impl.dart
[Error - 7:19:24 PM] Request textDocument/hover failed.
  Message: Invalid file path
  Code: -32003 
/Users/benjaminfarquhar/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/hive-1.4.4+1/lib/src/hive_impl.dart
[Error - 7:19:25 PM] Request textDocument/hover failed.
  Message: Invalid file path
  Code: -32003 
/Users/benjaminfarquhar/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/hive-1.4.4+1/lib/src/hive_impl.dart
[Error - 7:19:33 PM] Request textDocument/hover failed.
  Message: Invalid file path
  Code: -32003 
/Users/benjaminfarquhar/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/hive-1.4.4+1/lib/src/hive_impl.dart
```

I didn't use to get them. Any ideas on how to fix?

I have tried changing the settings.json dart sdk setting from null to my dart sdk location: `"dart.sdkPath": "/usr/local/opt/dart/libexec"`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a bug (see https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/2764) when using the LSP Preview. It's been fixed, although the fix might not have reached the stable version of Flutter yet.

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue in vscode v-1.58.2,I googled it, some said to uninstall/install the flutter sdk, but after tracing a lot, the origin of the error , which was  keeps on generating, whenever i hover, or clicked any part of the code.

### Origin of Error

After including  a code in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/transparent.png" />
```

which later on i commented and removed.

### Solution

I just simply performed these steps...

[image]

and the problem got solved.

I Hope this could help someone.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I got this error in `main.dart` (not in .pub-cache) on a project I'd been working on a while, when I was doing some cleanup and hovered on a warning:

[image: warning example]

I clicked on the "quick fix" for the "Use key in widget constructors" warning, which added the `const...` line below:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
```

After this, hovering over elements of the code kept generating the same error message you got.  Deleting the new `const...` line gets rid of the problem.

I had tried the other solution about "close editor" "close folder" "close window" but didn't have any luck, nor had I modified my AndroidManifest.xml and it didn't contain that bit of code in it.

Comment: If you can reproduce this and share the code that triggers it, please do file issues on GitHub, as it's likely an analysis server bug that's different to the one noted as being fixed above.

Comment: @DannyTuppeny Yeah, I just pulled that version from source control and if I add the `const` there it happens in v 1.64.2.  I'll file an issue, thanks!

Comment: @DannyTuppeny I filed that issue https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/3860, and it includes a very stripped down version of the project so it can be reproduced.

Comment: Thanks! I'll follow up on the issue :-)