# Request textDocument/codeAction failed. Message: Invalid file path Code: -32003

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

This error is showing all of a sudden when I opened a Flutter project.  When I tap the editor, this message is showing,

[image]

Also, the editor is not suggesting anything, not even error messages.

The last thing I did was installed the GitLens extension and initialize a repo for the first time.

Reinstalled VS Code and disabled all the extensions still no result. Can someone help me with the issue?

VS code version: 1.59.1

Flutter: 2.2.2

Dart: 2.13.3

Answer (score 1):

I just updated my flutter with the *flutter upgrade* command. Now my version is 2.2.3 and it has solved the issue.

Comment: Thank you for posting back the solution.  Please "accept" this answer when you get a chance.  See also this thread: [flutter - viewing .pub-cache files gives Request textDocument/documentSymbol failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65434751)